# How to: Avoid a bunch of useless Auto Draft ID entries related in posts table and disable autosave feature in 'post-new.php'?

Tags: core-modifications, autosave

I got it! Buuuuut I had to edit 2 core files, yes! 2 core files :(

I know is not a cool plugin hack, but maybe a cool patch for WP, Im using 3.3.1 version.

Well, here is my little hack/contribution:

**wp-admin/post-new.php**

## 1 Comment:

```
//wp_enqueue_script('autosave');
```

## 2 Change:

```
$post = get_default_post_to_edit( $post_type, true );
$post_ID = $post->ID;
```

by:

```
$post       = array();
$post_ID    = 0;
```

**wp-admin/post.php**

## 1 Change:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['post'] ) )
    $post_id = $post_ID = (int) $_GET['post'];
elseif ( isset( $_POST['post_ID'] ) )
    $post_id = $post_ID = (int) $_POST['post_ID'];
else
    $post_id = $post_ID = 0;
```

by:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['post'] ) ) {

    $post_id = $post_ID = (int) $_GET['post'];

} elseif ( isset( $_POST['post_ID'] ) ) {

    if ( empty($_POST['post_ID']) ) {

        $post_type = wp_kses($_POST['post_type']);

        if( !post_type_exists($post_type) ) {

            $post_type = 'post';

        }

        check_admin_referer('update-' . $post_type . '_' . (int) $_POST['post_ID']);

        global $user_ID;

        $defaults = array(
                            'post_status'   => 'draft',
                            'post_type'     => $post_type,
                            'post_author'   => (int) $user_ID,
                    );

        $postarr    = wp_parse_args( $_POST, $defaults );

        $post_ID    = wp_insert_post($postarr);

        $post_id    =  (int) $post_ID;

        redirect_post($post_id);

        exit;   

    } else {

        $post_id = $post_ID = (int) $_POST['post_ID'];

    }



} else {

    $post_id = $post_ID = 0;

}
```

I am using JQuery to hide: add media stuff. Just only a unique ID entry is created in posts table (and not a bunch of useless Auto Draft entries related) and media stuff will be visible after user manually saves current post.

**Rare behavior:
When a user logins for the first time and is redirected to Dashboard, WP creates an Auto Draft entry in posts table, hmmm, crazy! Somebody knows why it works like that?**

A better solution: perhaps not altering at any chance core files? It will be a great one! For example, with a checkbox in Settings to check or uncheck if we want the "autosave" feature or not (get_option). Somebody else wants to apply the patch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the "quick press" dash widget is the one responsible, you must unset all "core" widgets with some code in functions.php, and they wont let us disable on post-new.php

Answer (score 7):

Read the thread [Disable/ Stop "auto-draft" posts](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2012-February/042398.html) on wp-hackers to understand why this is a very bad idea.

Let me quote the explanations from [@Otto](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2232/otto):

> Auto-drafts exist because of the fact that multiple users can create
>    new posts at the same time. If two people enter post-new at roughly
>    the same moment, then have their first autosaves occur nearly
>    simultaneously, then there is a race condition that can cause one of
>    them to get back the wrong post ID, which will cause a post to be
>    overwritten/lost when they then continue editing the post.
>
> The auto-draft creates the post and gets the ID of the new post before
>    the editing screen is displayed, thus preventing two simultaneous
>    authors from accidentally having the same post ID in the data in their
>    browser.

[Source](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2012-February/042402.html)

> Auto-drafts are automatically deleted after 7 days of going unused.
>   They're self-cleaning, basically. No need to worry about them.
>
> They also go away when the first auto-save occurs while writing a new
>   post.

[Source](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2012-February/042401.html)

You should disable the **Quick draft** on the admin page, because that creates a new auto-draft whenever you load it.

Besides that, you solve a non-existent problem in a way that makes further updates impossible. Stop wasting your valuable time, do [something useful](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/unanswered) instead. :)

Comment: I thought MySQL can handle that, but is nice to learn about it from WP point of view. Cool to know about self-cleaning. Well Im going to do something useful as sleep a couple of hours. Thanks. But I still think a lot of IDs in post table is a kind of nasty solution, maybe Im 100% wrong :)